# Loop model data and list it out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to loop through data that is passed to my view in a model object. I want to list out the property name and the property value of each of the model properties, even if they are null. I have been at this for a few hours and have tried googling it but cannot get any good examples that work.

I got this to list out all of the properties of the current object, however cannot get the values:

```
 @model List<object>
 @foreach (var obj in Model)
 {
  var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
  foreach (var property in properties)
   {
    string name = null;
    var value = ""
    try
    {
         name = property.Name;
        value = property.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(property, null).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        <p>@e</p>

    }
    finally
    {
        <p>@name - @value</p>
    }

}
```

And the controller code:

```
            RootobjectPlayerData obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootobjectPlayerData>(jsonstring);
            List<object> list = new List<object>();
            list.Add(obj.data.accountinfo);
            list.Add(obj.data.accountinfo.statistics);
            list.Add(obj.data.accountinfo.statistics.clan);
            list.Add(obj.data.accountinfo.statistics.company);
            list.Add(obj.data.accountinfo.statistics.all);
            list.Add(obj.data.accountinfo.statistics.historical);
            list.Add(obj.data.accountinfo.statistics.team);
            return View(list);
```

I am able to do a break point and view all of the data within each of the objects, however I cannot get it to print out on screen.

Comment: Do you get any output?

Comment: Yes, all of the properties list out, and then an exception lists out due to my catch block. I tried googleing the exception with what I was trying to do and could not figure it out. `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Your variable names are letting you down. If you use more descriptive variables, your error would be clearer to you.

Comment: Why not create a typed view instead of reflection

Comment: @EdChapel - You are correct. I was trying to follow some examples I found online after struggling forever and it was just faster to use the same variable names they had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are getting the property value incorrectly. You should get the value from the object you have, but not from the type of the property:

```
value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(obj, null)
```

Secondly, try to loop only through data that's not null:

```
@foreach (var obj in Model.Where(w => w != null))
```

Comment: -Edit. Sorry I just realized you changed the x at the front as well. I just tried your solution again and I am getting a different exception. `System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.`

Comment: Are you sure that all the list variables are not null?

Comment: So once again, I used the wrong variable. this is what worked.
`value = i.GetType().GetProperty(x.Name).GetValue(i, null).ToString();`
However, it will still occasionally throw a null exception. I will have to figure out which ones are throwing the exception. The `.Where(w => w != null)` did not fix the few null ones. However I am getting most of the data so I am on my feet now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the values from `i`, not `x`.

```
try
{
     name = x.Name;
    // Wrong
    // value = x.GetType().GetProperty(x.Name).GetValue(x, null).ToString();
    // Correct
    value = x.GetValue(i, null).ToString();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    <p>@e</p>

}
```